# ScheduledJobs on Google Container Engine (kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Did someone has an experience running scheduled job? Due to the [guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/scheduled-jobs/), ScheduledJobs available since 1.4 with enabled runtime **batch/v2alpha1**

So I was ensured with `kubectl api-versions` command:

```
autoscaling/v1
batch/v1
batch/v2alpha1
extensions/v1beta1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1
```

But when I tried sample template below with command `kubectl apply -f job.yaml`

```
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
kind: ScheduledJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: 0/1 * * * ?
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I got error

```
error validating "job.yaml": error validating data: couldn't find type: v2alpha1.ScheduledJob; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

It's possible that feature still not implemented? Or I made some error during template creation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `kubectl version` reports server 1.4.5 and client 1.4.4 installed

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I think I resolved this issue. ScheduledJobs is currently in alpha state and Google Container Engine supports this feature only for clusters with **additionally enabled** APIs. I was able to create such cluster with command:

`gcloud alpha container clusters create my-cluster --enable-kubernetes-alpha`

As a result now I have limited 30 day cluster with full feature support. I can see scheduled jobs with `kubectl get scheduledjobs` as well as create new ones with templates.

You can find more info about alpha clusters [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/container/clusters/create).